# Dell OpenMagage web server "crashes" after logging in

Tags: 16.04, dell, crash, webserver

I just installed Dell OpenManage v8.4 on Ubuntu Server 16.04.  I have OpenManage setup serverside, however, I need to use the web UI for some other config.  The thing is, I can't login to the web UI because the web server "crashes".  If I log in with the wrong user id/password, it denies access, which is what it's supposed to do.  However, if I log in with the correct user id/password it crashes after login (images attached).  I can't confirm that it is crashing because after I try to log in on one client if I go to a different client the web server doesn't work at all.  In order to get the web server working again, I have to restart Ubuntu because restarting the web server using systemctl doesn't work.  I should also note that OpenManage CLI still works (omconfig, omreport, etc.).

Thanks in advance.

Images after login:
[After login 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gxVq.png)
[After login 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfS1u.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem too with Ubuntu 16.04. Problem is the `/home` folders are encrypted.

Each time you login, `dsm_om_connsvc.service` crashes.

The solution is then, to decrypt the `/home` folders (to do with every one of your home folders if you want to back them up and you have stuff in them) and to remove the `encryptfs` utility like this :

- back up your home dir :

  ```
  sudo cp -rp /home/username /home/username.backup
  ```
- log as an other account you created with a password and sudo rights and do this :

  ```
  sudo rm -rf /home/username
  sudo rm -rf /home/username.backup/.ecryptfs
  ```
- remove the encryption utility :

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove ecryptfs-utils
  ```
- then restore your backup home folder:

  ```
  sudo mv /home/username.backup /home/username
  ```
- now restart OMSA :

  ```
  /opt/dell/srvadmin/sbin/srvadmin-services.sh restart
  ```

and login with your username and password should work.

I helped myself with this link (to remove the encryption from your system) :

https://www.howtogeek.com/116179/how-to-disable-home-folder-encryption-after-installing-ubuntu/